# Google Protobuf check if field has been modified

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

Let's say I have this

```
test::User user;
user.SerializeFromString(str_user);
insert_to_sql_db(user); // putting it in sql makes some fields searchable

// we process some events and any of the user fields may change.
// ...

/* here I would like to have a list of fields that changed 
without keeping state for each field. */
update_to_sql_db(user);
```

In other words, I would like only the "dirty" fields so I can do an sql `update` on a few fields instead of all of them. Is there any way of detecting changed fields in protobuf? Are there any other message protocol libraries that generate the is_dirty() function I need?

**Update**

Here's a temporary solution I came up with to filter the "dirty" fields. It involves making a copy of the original message and keeping it around for comparison later.

```
std::vector<google::protobuf::FieldDescriptor const*> dirty(google::protobuf::Message const &mold, google::protobuf::Message const &mnew)
{
  std::vector<google::protobuf::FieldDescriptor const*> fields, dirty;
  auto r= mold.GetReflection();
  r-> ListFields(mold, &fields);
  for(auto &fp: fields)
    if(fp-> type()== google::protobuf::FieldDescriptor::TYPE_INT32 && r-> GetInt32(mold, fp)!= r-> GetInt32(mnew, fp))
      dirty.push_back(fp);
    else if(fp-> type()== google::protobuf::FieldDescriptor::TYPE_STRING && r-> GetString(mold, fp)!= r-> GetString(mnew, fp))
      dirty.push_back(fp);
    else if(fp-> type()== google::protobuf::FieldDescriptor::TYPE_DOUBLE && r-> GetDouble(mold, fp)!= r-> GetDouble(mnew, fp))
      dirty.push_back(fp);
  return dirty;
}
```

// P.S. I know how to compare doubles, this was just a demo.

Comment: I think cloning and comparing is the only way. The protobuf code is optimised for sending and receiving; everything else is secondary. You could compare the encoded buffer before and after - if identical, nothing changed. May not help much of course.

Comment: You might want to use [MessageDifferencer](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.util.message_differencer) for comparison of old and new messages...